# JSON parsing error using JQuery-1.7.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-1.5, jquery-1.7

I am Using DataTable 1.7.5 along with JQuery-1.7.1.min.js and getting a JSON parsing ERROR. While looking through several Online forums it was suggested to upgrade the validator plugin of JQuery-1.5.1.min.js but nothing about the validator of JQuery-1.7.1.min.js.Does any body has any suggestion regarding this issue ?

```
Table HTML:
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>                              
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Shpr</th>
                            <th>Org</th>
                            <th>Cne</th>
                            <th>Dest</th>
                            <th>Dep Dt</th> 
                            <th>LR No</th>
                            <th>Asset No</th>
                            <th>Curr Dt</th>
                            <th>Spd km/h</th>
                            <th>Waypoint1</th>
                            <th>Waypoint2</th>
                            <th>SDA</th>
                            <th>DETA</th>   
                            <th>AMC</th>                                                        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

                "aLengthMenu" : [[-1, 10, 25, 50, 100], ["All", 10, 25, 50, 100]],
                "iDisplayLength" : -1,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                //"sScrollY": "300px",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sAjaxSource": "ReportAction.do?process=home",
                "bDeferRender":true,
                "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "<%=localrequestedURL %>media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }       
            });
```

JSON Data:

```
result = session.createSQLQuery(sql_homepage).list();
String final_data = gson.toJson(result);
final_message = "{\"aaData\":"+final_data+"}";
```

1.The variable sql_homepage refers to a select query to the database.
2.The variable final_message is passed to the action class which passes the data to the JSP.

Comment: Is there a syntax error in your JSON? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: No there is no Syntax Error in JSON

Comment: post your json data or validate your json data here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was from an invisible character that got saved to the database. It is best to use a json validator to see where your error is. I used this one: http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html and this one http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

datatables is super finickey about the JSON it will parse. I has to be 100% perfect and I ended up needing to create a php function to make the JSON object string instead of just using php function json_encode

Comment: Link provided does not help in understanding the use of JSON Validator in the code. Can you explain the answer with some code ?

Comment: You don't put it in your code, you put your JSON into the parser. They have instructions on their sites. Whatever JSON you are returning to datatables, either paste it into the parser or put it on a page accessible via a url and put the url into the parser.